# What was the international reaction (political level) to ethnic cleansing in Bhutan?

Tags: human-rights, bhutan, demographics

There is very little information on Wikipedia about [ethnic cleansing in Bhutan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnic_cleansing_in_Bhutan). It is also connected to [Gross National Happiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_National_Happiness#Implementation_of_GNH_in_Bhutan) concept:

> GNH has been described by critics as a propaganda tool used by the
>   Bhutanese government to distract from ethnic cleansing and human
>   rights abuses it has committed

However I see little information about international reaction (at political level, not only from organizations like [Human Rights Watch](https://www.hrw.org/news/2008/02/01/bhutans-ethnic-cleansing)).

**Question:** What was the international reaction to ethnic cleansing in Bhutan?

Comment: The wiki page about this ethnic cleansing is extremely thin. Can you add a link to Human Right Watch's (or another organization's) reports about it ?

Comment: @Evargalo - I think https://www.hrw.org/news/2008/02/01/bhutans-ethnic-cleansing is one good example.

Comment: I found an article with US Secretary of State voicing the US official position in 2007, but more about the refugees than about the ethnic cleansing *per se* . however: " 'The US and many other international communities do believe that Bhutan has a moral obligation with people who are genuinely Bhutanese citizens, to let them come home,' [Ms. Sauerbrey] said. " http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/south_asia/7082586.stm

Comment: @Evargalo - yes, this is a good answer, although I was expecting something at United Nations or similar level.